# Pip не устанавливает библиотеки

Tags: python, pip

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/mbg9sks92m34b5_ft9zns3v40000gn/T/pip-install-bwbxpgab/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/mbg9sks92m34b5_ft9zns3v40000gn/T/pip-install-bwbxpgab/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/sf/mbg9sks92m34b5_ft9zns3v40000gn/T/pip-record-vgjjx5r2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame
     cwd: /private/var/folders/sf/mbg9sks92m34b5_ft9zns3v40000gn/T/pip-install-bwbxpgab/pygame/
Complete output (218 lines):
running install
...
copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
running build_ext
building 'pygame.gfxdraw' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/SDL_gfx
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src_c/gfxdraw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/gfxdraw.o
In file included from src_c/gfxdraw.c:33:
In file included from src_c/pygame.h:32:
src_c/_pygame.h:216:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
---
For help with compilation see:
    https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
To contribute to pygame development see:
    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
---
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/mbg9sks92m34b5_ft9zns3v40000gn/T/pip-install-bwbxpgab/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/mbg9sks92m34b5_ft9zns3v40000gn/T/pip-install-bwbxpgab/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/sf/mbg9sks92m34b5_ft9zns3v40000gn/T/pip-record-vgjjx5r2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Ну так черным по белому ж написано - fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found (не находит файл SDL.h). Посмотрите зависимости, сверьте версии питона

Comment: Вам нужно установить SDL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992243/pip-install-pygame-sdl-h-file-not-found